# How to add new dropdown when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, web

I want to have a drop down list of names of managers. I have a button "add". How it is that a new drop down will display after I click "add"? Thanks :)

I don't know if it needs Javascript or PHP so please help. Thanks.

Comment: Or PHP. depends where you want the dropdown to be generated. Maybe show us what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* btn click event */
    $('#addmore').click(function(){
        /* append selectbox where you want */
        $("#target").append('<select><option value="">select</option></select>')
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can add a new manager like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("dropDownId");
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = "Manager John";
select.add(option, 0);
```